# Handling pressing android back button while keyboard visible

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a edittext upon clicking that one keyboard appears and I have another layout which appears on edittext is pressed and if I click back button of android the keyboard disappears. I'm trying to find a listener which responds to on back pressed when keyboard is visible. I tried onbackpressed, but that will not get triggered when keyboard is visible. Please suggest any solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest one solution.It may not be perfect.

1)Override the on back pressed method.

2)In on back pressed method detect if keyboard is visible or not,using following code

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
        if (heightDiff > 100) { // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
            ... do something here
        }
     }
});
```

3)You can do the operations when keyboard visibility is detected as per your requirement onbackpressed.